# dictionary from IDs based on an ID column to multiple columns of time series data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, time-series

I have a unique type of excel sheet where the first column has IDs and the other columns are date, param1(@dates), param2(@dates), param3(@dates).

For storing, plotting, processing, accessing, and clustering of this dataset I am thinking of making a dictionary from ID strings as keys to different time series columns.

Can you think of a more efficient way of loading this type of dataset, that makes further plotting, processing, accessing, and clustering easier?

I also thought of creating separate excel sheet for each ID, but again loading them does not seem to be that efficient.

```
IDS   date  param1   param2  param3 
A    1-June
A    1-July
A    1-Aug
A    1-Sept
B    1-June
B    1-July
B    1-Aug
B    1-Sept
```

Comment: Have you thought about just using `.groupby()`?

Comment: Hard to say without specific applications. Personally, I'd prefer the date as a `datetime` but in this form it's easy to group (by either ID, or date), or plot time-series (by group), so not sure what you'd change.

Comment: @rahlf23 groupby should not be a good option since I will lose the time series nature of param1, param2, param3.